# csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion / IDE0200 not working correctly in Visual Studio 17.8.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-8.0, editorconfig

I have a single `.editorconfig` placed in the root of the solution and added as a solution item with the following content:

```
[*.cs]
...
dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression = true:suggestion
csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion = false:suggestion
```

Then I have 2 pieces of code with 2 IDE suggestions in the error list:

```
internal delegate int GetRowsCountDelegate();
...
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // Use collection expression for array (IDE0300)
GetRowsCountDelegate getRowsCount =
    () => rowsDeletedParameter.Value.As<int>(); // Remove unnecessary lambda expression (IDE0200)
```

I understand where the first one comes from: the first setting in the `.editorconfig` enables it. By changing it to `false:suggestion` and seeing the suggestion go away I can verify that Visual Studio knows about and makes use of my `.editorconfig`.

The second warning is what the question is about. The `.editorconfig` tells to NOT prefer method groups over lambdas, but VS still gives me a suggestion nevertheless.

I know I can fix it on the place with a `#pragma warning disable` or via `SuppressMessageAttribute`, but I don't want to do it every single time I'm writing a lambda.

So I'm basically asking if I'm overlooking something or maybe there is someone else who also encountered it, so I can confirm it's a VS bug and provide feedback on it.

[Remove unnecessary lambda expression (IDE0200) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0200)

Comment: You can also add `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0200.severity = none` to editor config

Comment: Hi, I tried Guru Stron's suggestion and added "dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0200.severity = none" to editorconfig. This does work, does this work for you?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT, yes, it does, but ideally I would like to have it working out-of-box according to the ```csharp_style_prefer_method_group_conversion``` setting without additional warnings being ignored explicitly.

Comment: At present, you can only add "dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0200.severity = none" or use "#pragma warning disable". It is difficult to achieve "out of the box" by relying on editorconfig alone.